# TRANSISTOR COLLECTOR COMMON QUESTION

Tags: transistors

This image is from the Boylestad Electronic Devices book, it corresponds to the common collector configuration; because in part (a), the collector base junction is directly polarized if to function in the active zone it should not be inversely polarized?, that is, positive terminal in n and negative terminal in p
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain your confusion. Perhaps your question is clear in your mind, but there isn't enough information for us to help you. Posting the same question again without substantial changes won't really help because we won't have any more information to understand your query.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Vbc is never biased forward in linear more and is always less than Vbe when saturated and Vbc >|-1| for better linear mode, for lower THD.

That means Vce>2V for better linearity.